# ajax if hover is maintained for 500ms and doesn't fire if hover stops

Tags: jquery, ajax, hover, settimeout, delay

I'd like to delay an ajax call until hover is maintained for 500ms

```
obj.hover(function(){ 
var t = setTimeout(function() {
    ajax_search();
}, 500);
}, function(){ 
clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
});
```

does delay the ajax but it still fires even if I have stopped hovering.

It's being used for a map with lots of hover regions and I'd like to minimise ajax calls to those the user indicates with a longer hover. At the moment it fires for every single hover and on heroku/facebook app and chained hovers are killing the response for users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting the data on the hover target. You're aquiring the handle (t) but not doing a `$(this).data("timeout", t);` after the setTimeout call.